# I cannot figure out why `netdom join` is not working

Tags: command-line-interface, active-directory, domain-controller

I cannot get `netdom join` working on Windows Server 2008 R2.

```
netdom join bananas /domain:fruitland.local /userd:fruitland\Administrator /passwordd:*

Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

The command failed to complete successfully.
```

The local admin account I am using is has the same name and password as the domain admin account.  I've double checked DNS and passwords.  I can ping the DC.  The DC accepted `netdom join` from a Windows Server 2003 R2 machine earlier.  I've made sure that the older version of `netdom` for pre-Vista is not in the path.

However, when I go through the GUI `System Properties > Computer Name` and enter the same domain, username and password, it works fine.  The only difference I can see is that the user account details dialogue box is already set to use a domain, with the top level domain at the end.

So I tried:

```
netdom join bananas /domain:fruitland.local /userd:fruitland.local\Administrator /passwordd:*
```

...but that did not work either.  I get the same error.

I must be getting something wrong, as the GUI method works fine.

Comment: All machines mentioned are Hyper-V virtual machines, but I cannot see how this could make a difference.  I just thought I'd mention it just in case it does.

Comment: While being logged in to your local admin account, if you make it just "netdom join bananas /domain:fruitland.local" what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While being logged into your local admin account, just type in

```
netdom join bananas /domain:fruitland.local
```